# Auto zoom out from textarea in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, text, uiwebview, keyboard, zooming

I am using UIWebView in my app, and creating a form in HTML. I am doing this to allow the users to zoom into text.

Although I have ran into an issue with textarea

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="35" id="freeComment" name="freeComment"></textarea>
```

When a user clicks onto the textarea, it auto zooms in and a keyboard appears. Which is what I want. But when the user is done typing and presses "Done" on the keyboard, it stays zoomed into the textarea. How can I have this auto zoom out after pressing done?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding this in the head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

This, however, disables the users ability to zoom-in or zoom-out anywhere else on the page unless its in the form (which zooms automatically).